# gwt canvas- handling events altogether differently

Tags: events, gwt, canvas, handler

Gwt HTML5 Canvas wrapper can responds to mouse and keyboard events, it binds to 5 - 6 types of different events, my question is, it is possible to define entirely new event system such as CanvasEvent (and related handler CanvasEventHandler extends to GwtEvent etc), bind this to canvas object and then handle all events differently using a handler interface methods will be something like onDraw(), onDrag(), onMove(), onSelect() etc.

I dont have good clarity of GWT event system but i want to know is this possible without individuality attaching separate event handlers to form a logic for handling my problem, can I access all possible event as one consolidated object and fire custom event based on conditions. What would be the best way to do it, there are threads with GWT custom events but they include senders, whereas in my case sender is already present (Canvas)

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly - remember that all of the GwtEvent objects are completely artificial and are based off of events fired from the native JavaScript. That JavaScript event object, (which comes in via `onBrowserEvent`) gets wrapped up as a `ClickEvent` or a `KeyDownEvent` based on the details of the original object, and then fired off via the internal `HandlerManager` instance. In the same way, you could listen for a `MouseDownEvent`, set some state, then if a `MouseMoveEvent` occurs, fire your own `CanvasDrag` event. You'd probably stop listening to those move events once a `MouseUpEvent` happens, then you would issue something like a `CanvasDropEvent`. If isntead the `MouseUpEvent` occurred right away with no move, you could trigger a `CanvasSelectEvent` (or you might have something else in mind for that select event).

Each of these new event types you declare then might contain specifics about whatever is going on. For example, while a MouseMoveEvent just has the element that the mouse is over and the x/y coords, you might be indicating *what* is being dragged around the page. That might be in the form of the shape that was last clicked, or even the data it represents.

Yes, the 'sender', or source, is already there, but it'll be easier to use if you expose some kind of a method to add handlers like `addCanvasDragHandler`, etc. This is *not* required - all users of your code could just use `addHandler`, but it does make it a little ambiguous about whether or not the widget supports the event in question. You would then call `fireEvent` on the canvas object to make all handlers of that event type listen.

Or, you could make a new class that contains an internal `Canvas` widget - possibly a `Composite` object or just something that implements `IsWidget` (Canvas has a private constructor, so you can't subclass it). This would enable you to add your own particular handlers, and keep your own HandlerManager/EventBus to track the events you are concerned with.

Comment: that works!, to fire a complex event those simple handlers must be implemented to run in parallel. LOL my whole code is wrapped inside single class "public class CanvasEvent extends GwtEvent<CanvasEventHandler> implements
  MouseDownHandler, MouseMoveHandler, MouseUpHandler"

Comment: Minor quibble, but remember that there is no 'parallel' in GWT - all code in the browser runs in a single thread. You can fire off several events, one after another, but each will run its full course before the next one starts up. This is the nature of the JavaScript VM in the browser. You should treat it more or less like parallel though - that will encourage you to write more asynchronous (aka non-blocking) code, which result in a more responsive experience for the user.

Comment: oh yes, "the old single thread saying of javascript", i will keep that in mind.